# Where to buy a microfiber towel in Taipei?

Tags: shopping, taiwan, taipei

I'm not sure whether this question is suitable for Travel Stackexchange, but where (in which store chains for example) can I buy a (preferably microfiber) towel in Taipei (near the Main Station, if that's relevant)?

Comment: Hm, I found plenty of places to buy them in lots of 1000, but nothing for buying a single towel.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure there are plenty of options, but I would try the nearest Decathlon : https://m.decathlon.tw/mobile_en/swimming-c122253.html

It looks like there are at least three of them in Taipei.